Kyber prime modulus p and base generator g
I am trying to learn more about Crystals Kyber. I am playing around with a Java implementation. I am only focussing on Kyber-512 for now, I have locally changed the source code in order to remove the DER PKCS8/X.509 encodings so my public/private keys are simple byte arrays instead of objects, which I succeeded. Everything is still compiling and I can successfully share a secret.
Inside this implementations KyberPrivateKey.java and KyberPublicKey.java classes are 2 large variables p and g, called "prime modulus and base generator", which in his implementation example always seems to be a default value (which is defined in the file KyberParams.java).
I do not understand what this p and g are, I cannot find a reference in their specification about such large prime modulus and base generator. It seems it is only used in this PKCS8/X.509 encodings and seem to work fine without any reference to those variables.
Am I not understanding this correctly? Could someone explain me what those variables are and why they seem not necessary?

In the title you denote the base generator with $g$ while in the text you denote it as $q$. Could you specify which is the correct one?

Whoops, I mean p and g, I have edited it, thanks.

Moreover, without finding a reference through their specification, my best guesses would be: $p$ denotes the modulus (which is prime). You can also find it as $q$ sometimes. This means that the computations of the protocol happen in modular arithmetic with modulus $p$. The base generator $g$ probably denotes the generator of the group that the computations are happening. With a generator, you can "construct" the group using only $g$ and its powers ($g^2,g^3,...$).

That is interesting, but what I do not understand is why I can remove them without breaking the entire algorithm.

This is curious.
The prime p=0xfca682ce8e12caba26efccf7110e526db078b05edecbcd1eb4a208f3ae1617ae01f35b91a47e6df63413c5e12ed0899bcd132acd50d99151bdc43ee737592e17 is a 512-bit prime with $p-1=2\times 4243\times 101833\times C_{483}$ where $C_{483}$ is a 482-bit composite.
The number g=0x678471b27a9cf44ee91a49c5147db1a9aaf244f05a434d6486931d2d14271b9e35030b71fd73da179069b32e2935630e1c2062354d0da20a6c416e50be794ca4 is a $C_{483}$ power mod $p$ (and one would guess more precisely a $\ell$th power for some pirme $\ell|C_{483}$). In particular it is not a primitive root (generator for the multiplicative group mod $p$).
These numbers should have no relevance whatsoever to Kyber. My best guess is that they are a legacy stub from where a Diffie-Hellman test params file has been used as a template for a public key parameters file. They should certainly be possible to delete without affecting Kyber functionality. If you are especially concerned, you could email the github owner.

Well that explains why (after rewriting to remove the encodings), I was left over with unused variables p and g. Thanks for the explination for both those numbers and why I do not need them.
